# when the recordViewController is deinited,how Can I release the Objects with AudioKit

Tags: audiokit

I have push the recordViewController that record audio by AudioKit from homeViewController which is an emptyViewController, it crashed.

Comment: so the cresh happend when I push the recordViewController and pop to rootViewController,and then push it

Comment: the error like this:[avae] AVAEInternal.h:70:_AVAE_Check: required condition is false: [AVAEGraphNode.mm:804:CreateRecordingTap: (nullptr == Tap())]
2018-03-14 22:08:11.136182+0800 Recorder[13419:139110] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: nullptr == Tap()'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to insert the code you have tried until now and specify what was the expected output and how it didn't work as you expected